# Using Stack To Print Prime Numbers

Tags: c++, stack, prime-factoring

I am trying to print out all prime factors of any given number by the user. So far I was able to get the code to check and print the prime numbers however, I am having issues with reprinting the number multiple times. Ex: Enter a prime number: 9 , Program prints: 3 * 3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;
    stack<int> PrimeFactor;

    cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The prime factors of " << number << " in descending order are: ";

    if((number % 2) == 0)
        PrimeFactor.push(2);
    if((number % 3) == 0)
       PrimeFactor.push(3);
    if((number % 5) == 0)
       PrimeFactor.push(5);
    if((number % 7) == 0)
       PrimeFactor.push(7);
    if((number % 11) == 0)
       PrimeFactor.push(11);
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(number); i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0 && i % 2 != 0 && i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 !=0 && i % 7 != 0 && i % 11 != 0)
        {
            PrimeFactor.push(i);
        }
    }

    while(!PrimeFactor.empty())
    {
        cout << PrimeFactor.top() << " * ";
        PrimeFactor.pop();
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use those hardcoded `if`s for 2, 3, 5, 7 and 11?

Comment: _"I am having issues with reprinting ..."_ That's much too vague to ask here.

Comment: I just ran your code, and I only see one `3` printed

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I believe OP is referring to the problem of duplicated output

Comment: @DrewMcGowen yes, that is the OPs problem: the program does not "reprint" the 3.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Well, nice you're trying to guess something reasonable with this question. It's the OP's job to clarify though! As it is, the question is just off topic, and useless for any further researchers.

Comment: Not even attempting to print the second `3` is probably at least partly to blame for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns "3 *" because 3 is the only number ever pushed onto the stack, which means the logic you are using is wrong.

Think like this: for the number the user enters, you have to find the first prime that can divide the number, and then do the same for the result of the division, and so on.

A very simple pseudocode:

```
number = X;

can 2 divide X?
yes -> push 2; Y = X/2;

can 2 divide Y?
no
can 3 divide Y?
no
can <next prime> divide Y?
yes -> push <next prime>; Z = Y/<next prime>
```

This means your loop counter "i" should be incremented to the next prime, and not by one.

To point your error perfectly:
when i = 3, the condition i % 3 != 0 fails, and 3 doesn't get pushed onto the stack.
You shouldn't test if a number is prime dividing it by itself (which is what you are doing in the if condition), because you will always get 0 and a result that says it is not prime because of that.
If you remove "i % 3 != 0" from the if condition, you will see that you get the result that you expect: 3 * 3.

To avoid this, I recommend writing a simple isPrime(int x) function that checkes if a number is prime.

Comment: Upvoted for providing psuedocode, rather than full implementation.